# How to create PDF documents from my MS excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to create PDF documents from my MS excel files?  Hi guys, I need to create PDF documents from my MS excel files. How do I do it?
Anyone know how to convert word doc to pdf? Someone has given me a word doc in Thai language and wants to covert it to pdf and I have never converted .xls - .pdf, Need help.

Answer (score 3):

[Cutepdf](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/Writer.asp) writer installs itself as a "printer subsystem". This enables virtually any Windows applications (must be able to print) to create professional quality PDF documents  with just a push of a button.

Comment: Seconded - been using CutePDF for many, many moons. Really good bit of software. And at $0.00 it's just the right price too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have genuine copy of Windows then there is an ADD-ON for Office "Save as PDF" for every office work including word,excel, ppt etc ..

[Here is the download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1fc413c-6d89-4f15-991b-63b07ba5f2e5&displaylang=en) ..

Answer (score 0):

A free product [Free Excel / Xls to Pdf Converter 5.6](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/Free-Excel-Xls-to-Pdf-Converter.shtml):

> Free Excel/Xls to Pdf Converter is the
>   fast way to convert xls, xlsx, xlsm,
>   txt, htm, html to pdf format. After
>   converting, the content of the file
>   can reserve the original layout. It
>   can combine a host of sheets of one
>   book to a sheet.
>
> Limitations:
>
> - Converts only one file at a time
> - nag screen

If you prefer not to install any product, a free website can also do the conversion :
[ExpressPDF](http://www.expresspdf.com/ConvertWordToPdf.aspx) (email required).